# Can't choose a column of a data frame on Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot a figure on Python but I get a KeyError. I can't read the column "Cost per Genome" for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("Sequencing_Cost_Data_Table_Aug2021 - Data Table.csv") #The data can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1auLPEnAp0aI__zIyK9fKBAkLpwQpOFBx9qOWgJoh0xY/edit#gid=729639239

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(data["Date"],data["Cost per Genome"])
```

Comment: Run `data.columns` and see what columns are available to you

Comment: Ahh, I realized there was a space before and after "Cost per Genome", which is what caused the error..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either you have interpreted the data wrong into the Dataframe, of made an error with the plot. Read this. It might help you further: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

P.S. I couldn't acces your spreadsheet. It was request only